# computerChoice is not a function error

Tags: javascript

So I am having problems making a Rock, Paper and Scissors game.
I keep getting the error "TypeError: computerChoice is not a function"
I can see why this is happening, I just don't know how to fix it.

Heres my code;

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you chose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random(); 

console.log(computerChoice)

if (computerChoice < 0.33) 
{
    computerChoice("rock");
} 
else if (computerChoice < 0.66)
{
    computerChoice("paper");
} 
else (computerChoice < 1) 
{
    computerChoice("scissors");
}
```

Ive been told since my var isn't a function that is the problem, but how do I fix it.
I tried
var computerChoice = function (Math.random());
But it still didn't work.

Thanks for whoever can help me! :)

Comment: What do you imagine `computerChoice("rock");` does ?

Comment: No clue, i'm really new to this. And my question got -3. Very nice guys. Very nice.

Comment: Programing isn't just randomly putting words. There must be some logic.

Comment: I know, but I came here for help but instead i'm getting told i'm wrong.
Still waiting for a bit of help. :L

Comment: The question (still) is: what did you *want* `computerChoice("rock")` to do?

Comment: I am wanting it to go between values, I will post the question.

Comment: We have computerChoice but it now equals a random number between 0 and 1. We need to somehow translate this random number into a random choice of rock, paper, or scissors. How do we do this?!

If computerChoice is between 0 and 0.33, make computerChoice equal to "rock".
If computerChoice is between 0.34 and 0.66, make computerChoice equal to "paper".
If computerChoice is between 0.67 and 1, make computerChoice equal to "scissors".

Comment: Ok, you should have written that to the question. There's no way anyone could have guessed that.

Comment: @Cain, change the computerChoice calls to `computerChoice = “paper"` and similar. You need to assign the string to it, not call it with a the string.

Comment: TL:DR 
If math.random rolls
Between 0 and 0.33 it is rock
Between 0.33 and 0.67 it is paper
Between 0.67 and 1 it is scissors

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value to a variable. Here's the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Neoares/vespwott/

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you chose rock, paper or scissors?");
var rnd = Math.random(); 
var computerChoice;

if (rnd < 0.33) 
{
    computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if (rnd < 0.66)
{
    computerChoice = "paper";
} 
else 
{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
alert("random: "+rnd+"\ncomputerChoice: "+computerChoice);
```

Comment: That helps a lot. Thank you so much man, Can you explain the 
alert("random: "+rnd+"\ncomputerChoice: "+computerChoice);

Comment: The "\n" means new line when you place it inside a String :)

Comment: The alert just displays what the random choice was. Probably mostly for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much, is that last line needed, as most people who are getting this correct do not include that last line,
would console.log work fine?

Comment: The alert will show it as a pop up. If you're logging the choice some other way, you could omit it.

Comment: Thats all I needed to know, thanks so much guys for actually taking the time for helping me. I will hopefully finish my Rock, Paper, Scissors game now.